# VBA formula does not work properly

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I want to implement a formula in my VBA code. It should check if all values in a column are the same.

```
Dim intBB2 As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ISINcheck As String

ISINcheck = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(2, intBB2), Cells(LastRow, intBB2)), _
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(2, intBB2))) _
= WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(2, intBB2), Cells(LastRow, intBB2)))
```

the variables `intBB2` and `LastRow` are from previous code, which find the last row and the column, which the formula should take for the calculations.

If I replace the range references with the address of the range (e.g. I2:I120), it works. But as it is, it gives me an Application-defined or object-defined error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it this way

```
intValueToFind = Cells(2, intBB2).Value

For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Not Cells(i, intBB2).Value = intValueToFind Then
        ISINcheck = i
    End If
Next i


If ISINcheck = "" Then
    controlISIN = "N"
Else
    controlISIN = "Y"
End If
```

Probably not the most elegant but works

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: Yes, I received the same mistake

Comment: You should have said. Did you actually assign a value to those variables?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You need to qualify all your ranges with workbook/worksheets

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        ISINcheck = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(.Cells(2, intBB2), .Cells(LastRow, intBB2)), _
            .Range(.Cells(2, intBB2))) _
            = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range(.Cells(2, intBB2), .Cells(LastRow, intBB2)))
End With
```